# Can TR ID elements be shown and hidden with jQuery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have implemented jQuery validate recently to some of my web forms. I'm trying to employ more of it, replacing some older javascript code I have had in place for a while.

I have a situation where I am trying to show and hide ID elements on a TR tag. I have been searching this, but I'm mostly finding references to DIV tags, which I haven't been using, as opposed to ID elements on a TR tag, which I have been using. My question is basically can jQuery show and hide id elements on a TR tag? It's not looking like it and what I've been trying to write has not worked.

My current code is something of the sort here.

```
    <td colspan="5"><select name="acctloc" id="acctloc" class="inputtxtbox" onChange="msgSwap2a()"  required>
<option value="" selected>Please  select...</option>
<option value="Channel1">Channel 1</option>
<option value="Channel2">Channel 2</option>
<option value="Channel3">Channel 3</option>
<option value="Chan-Cust">Chan-Cust</option>
<option value="Network">Network</option>
<option value="SpecCust">Special Cust</option>
</select>


    <tr id="acctnetwork" style="display:">
    <td align="right"><label for="Acct_num">Acct Number:</label></td>
    <td colspan="5"><input name="Acct_num" type="text" id="Acct_num"  onChange="this.value = new chkLoan(this.value.trim());if (this.value == 'NaN' || this.value.length.trim() <10)  {alert ('That is not a valid Acct #. \n Please enter in format of ##-####-#######.'); this.value = ''; this.focus}" required>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="acctother" style="display:none">
    <td align="right"><p>Acct Number:-</p></td>
    <td colspan="5"><input name="Acct_num_sec" type="text" onChange="this.value=this.value.trim()" id="Acct_num_sec">
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="specialname" style="display:none">
    <td align="right">Special Acct Name (in lieu of number)</td>
    <td colspan="5"><input name="Acct_num_spec" type="text"  id="Acct_num_spec" onChange="convHeSpec();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="specr" style="display:none">
    <td align="right"></td>
    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#FF9933" class="pageContentHeading">ATTENTION: For security reasons these  orders for  special accounts must be placed using the customer's last name in the account number box.  When searching vendor website for the order, you must search by account name and address and not account number. </td>
    </tr>
```

I can add the other part of the code, but it's basically a block showing and hiding the ID elements with documentgetElementById, like this.

```
    if (form.acctloc.value == "Channel1" || form.acctloc.value   == "Channel2" || form.acctloc.value == "Channel3" || form.acctloc.value   == "Chan-Cust" ) { 
    document.getElementById('acctother').style.display='';
    document.getElementById('acct_loc').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('acctnetwork').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('specr').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('specialname').style.display='none';
    document.form.Acct_num.value == '';
    }
```

I understand that in jQuery you make the id element 
        $('acct_loc') 
rather than putting the whole documentgetElementById in front of it, but my main question is do I need to change up TR ID tags and wrap them in DIV tag ID elements instead?
Like instead of

```
     <tr id="specialname" style="display:none">
```

make it

```
     <div id="specialname" style="display:none">   ?
```

Any help and feedback is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: And I should have added, I guess, that the part with the doc getElement part is in the function, msgSwap2a().

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem with hiding a tr instead of a div. If you're using jquery now, try doing:

```
    $('#yourElementIDHere').css('display', 'none')
```

This will change the css property of whatever element you choose

Comment: OK, thank you. Also, I'm not sure if I specified or clarified it in the above, but I'm also resetting some field values to null as I make a similar, yet separate field visible.
As in this..    


         document.getElementById('specr').style.display='none';
         document.getElementById('specialname').style.display='none';
         document.form.Acct_num.value == '';      

Do I just then make it 
        $('Acct_num').value='';

Would that ^^ be correct?

Comment: The syntax is a little different. With JQuery, you generally set the value inside of the method call. For example, in the above example, you would use $("#Acct_num").val('') where you can set the value to whatever you want inside the (). JQuery methods are generally overloaded so that is you leave them empty, you return the value, but if you include a value, you are setting the value

Comment: No problem. Hope that helps! If so, help a brother out and upvote / choose the answer ;)

Comment: That does help, and I upvoted! : )  Addendum to comment. I'll post back upward in the code block with the question.

Comment: in lieu of...
        if (form.acctloc.value == "Channel1" || form.acctloc.value   == "Channel2" am I able to do if ('#acctloc.val()' == "Channel1"  II  '#acctloc.val()' == "Channel2") ? Is <-- this the correct syntax?

Comment: Close. You need to use the '$' syntax. So it will look like this:   ($('#acctloc').val() == "Channel1" || $('#acctloc').val() == "Channel2")

Comment: The $ replaces the document.getElementBy[whatever] syntax, but it means inside of parenthesis, you will need to specify what type of attribute you are searching for. This means where we have the '#' in front of the name for ID, a period in front for searching by class, or adding nothing will search for an element type such as div or input, etc

Comment: Wow! Thanks, Justin! That worked great. I am a complete novice with some areas of the jquery syntax - obviously! I now just need to see if there's a way, and I think there is, to apply conditional rules to a single field. Not multiple rules, but (multiple) conditional rules to a field. ...i.e., make it alpha only in one instance, numeric only in another, depending on a dropdown selection!  Greatly appreciate the help, sir!

Comment: Ok, strange. I have a similar setup here, and it's not responding the way I thought it should or would. For one, the display is not showing on the id element, On that note, I doubt the value is getting populated as I'd like it to, but I didn't view the source to see. Here's the code.